# How to export Firebase Realtime database to CSV?

Tags: firebase, csv, firebase-realtime-database

How would I export the firebase realtime database to CSV? I can see it is possible to export to JSON, but there is no option for CSV. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upto now firebase is not allowing to export database into a csv file. However,
you can export it to json, then convert the json file to csv format.

You can use the following sites to convert json to csv
https://codebeautify.org/json-to-csv

https://json-csv.com/

Comment: Thanks, but am looking for something more programatic!